# How does fmod() in c work compared with matlab mod()?

Tags: c, matlab, fmod, modulo

In matlab code

```
    Longitude =  mod(-1789.8916,360);
```

returns value 10.108325

But in C code

```
    Longitude = fmod(-1789.8916,360);
```

returns value -349.8916

I want the value same as in the c code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matlab `mod` function always returns a positive value, but the C `fmod` function (from C11 at least) will return a negative value if the first argument is negative. (In prior C standards the precise behaviour for a negative argument was up to the implementation).

So you can transform the matlab version by subtracting 360 (in this case) from the answer if the first argument is negative and the result greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

The `mod` function always returns a positive value in MATLAB, from C11 `fmod` returns a negative value if the first argument is negative.

You can use this function to mimic the behaviour of `fmod` in MATLAB

```matlab
function m = fmod(a, b)

    % Where the mod function returns a value in region [0, b), this
    % function returns a value in the region [-b, b), with a negative
    % value only when a is negative.

    if a == 0
        m = 0;
    else
        m = mod(a, b) + (b*(sign(a) - 1)/2);
    end

end
```

Explanation:

`sign(a)` is `1` when `a` is positive, or `-1` when `a` is negative.

`(sign(a) - 1)/2` is therefore `0` or `-1` respectively.

This causes `b` to be subtracted from the result if `a` is negative, giving the desired results range `[-b, b)`.